# How to decorate a component in angular.dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-decorator

I would like to provide a possibility to show my components in a bit different look and feel and thought using the decorator for it. Something like:

```dart
<body>
    <my-component my-decorator></my-component>
</body>
```

.

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: '.../my-component.html',
  cssUrl: '.../my-component.css',
  publishAs: 'comp',
)
class MyComponent {

  MyComponent(final Element element) {
    Logger.root.fine("MyComponent(): element = $element, element.attributes = ${element.attributes.keys}");
  }

}


@Decorator(selector: '[my-decorator]')
class MyDecorator {

  final Element element;

  @NgOneWay('my-decorator')
  var model; // is not used

  MyDecorator(this.element) {
    Logger.root.fine("MyDecorator(): element = $element, element.nodeName = ${element.nodeName}");
    Logger.root.fine("MyDecorator(): element.shadowRoot = ${element.shadowRoot}, element.parent = ${element.parent}");
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `my-decorator` is processed before `my-component` so it is getting null `shadowRoot` property in the injected `Element` object.

It would be possible to check on existence of the `my-decorator` attribute within the `my-component` backing class, but that is clearly polluting the design.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to replay from Marko Vuksanovic, the following is now returning the :

```dart
@Decorator(selector: '[my-decorator]')
class MyDecorator extends AttachAware {

  final Element element;

  @NgOneWay('my-decorator')
  var model; // is not used

  MyDecorator(this.element) {
    Logger.root.fine("MyDecorator(): element = $element, element.nodeName = ${element.nodeName}");
    Logger.root.fine("MyDecorator(): element.shadowRoot = ${element.shadowRoot}, element.parent = ${element.parent}");
  }

  void attach() {
    Logger.root.fine("attach(): element.shadowRoot = ${element.shadowRoot}");
  }

}
```

The question still remains how to modify the styling of the shadow DOM.

Thanks in advance for any comments/ideas/solutions.

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you provided some code that shows what you try to accomplish. Maybe just a `new Future(() { access the elements shadowRoot here });` might be sufficient.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How are you able to respond within 2 minutes?!  I will add minimal code ...

Comment: I had SO page open and I saw that a new question appeared, that's all - no magic, no tricks ;-)

Comment: Very happy to get such a quick response - proves that Dart rocks already. Regarding my question, is there alternative way to decorate a custom component?

Comment: You could fire an event in the components `onShadowRoot()` method and `element.on['on-shadow'].listen((e) => dosomething)` in the decorator. The disadvantage is that the component needs to be changed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you broke my formatting ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that you had more tags than just `<pre>...</pre>` Dart code often contains HTML fragments so it didn't look uncommon. Usually indenting is IMHO better than the `pre` tag. There is a button `{}` in the toolbar for that.

Comment: No worry. I used `<pre>` 'cause I needed **bold** to emphasize the change. I am not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: I understand. I changed it because I don't like to look at code without syntax-highlighting. I usually use comments to draw attention to specific code lines like ` somecode {} // <== I added this` like suggested http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question

Answer (score 2):

You can try using AttachAware and it's attach method. You should implement AttachAware interface in your decorator and/or component.

Here's link to Angular.dart docs - https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular-core-annotation.AttachAware

To change the styling of a ShadowDom component you can use element.shadowRoot to get the root of your web component. Shadow root is almost like 'document' object. You can use shadow root to get reference to any element and then you can easily modify it by applying styles as needed.

You could use something like
this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector('[some-attr]').innerHtml = "Modified by decorator" // disclaimer: not tested, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Interesting, I thought onShadowRoot would only work in a component.

Comment: Unfortunately `onShadowRoot` is not called in a `Decorator`.

Comment: @drasko-kokic, sorry, try using AttachAware and it's attach method instead of ShadowRootAware.onShadowRoot.

Comment: Even with the latest Dart SDK 1.4.0 the `element.shadowRoot.querySelector` is never returning any object. Any working samples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style tag to the shadowDom programmatically:

```dart
shadowRoot.append(new StyleElement()..text = ':host{background: red;}');
```

or

```dart
shadowRoot.append(new StyleElement()..text = "@import url('some.css')");
```